# Jquery-ui Tooltip not working with HTM Button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Jquery-ui tooltip function seemingly not working with button as the target.  Using jquery-ui version 1.9.2 and jquery version 1.8.3.

I created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CEaqw/1/) for my problem, and it seems to not function at all.  I'm completely stumped here.  Here's my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myBtn').tooltip({
        position: {
            my: "left top",
            at: "bottom"
        },
        content: function () {
            return "This tooltip is a function return value with <b>HTML content</b>";
        }
    });
});
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <button id="myBtn" class="text">My button</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh, now I see.  The element needs a title attribute to work.  Seems clear now, but I thought I should at least answer my own question.

Here's the [corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CEaqw/1/).  Note the `title="x"` attribute in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

[Tooltips](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#default) can be attached to any element. When you hover the element with your mouse, the **title attribute** is displayed in a little box next to the element, just like a native tooltip.

But as it's not a native tooltip, it can be styled. Any themes built with ThemeRoller will also style tooltips accordingly.

So to fix your issue you can set an empty title attribute like:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <button id="myBtn" title="" class="text">My button</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VSEQP/

Comment: If you don't want to add the title into the HTML you can also do it using jQuery `$('selector').attr('title', '');`